# Drop-down doesn't select the value when visible

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

When you select the family Room, you get 2 drop downs : 
1.Asking number of adults
2.Asking number of child
Once you select a number from 2nd dropdown, a 3rd dropdown gets visible.
For that i use explicit wait, but still it doesn't get selected don't know why?

Website=https://www.trivago.in/?aDateRange[arr]=2018-06-16&aDateRange[dep]=2018-06-20&aPriceRange[to]=0&aPriceRange[from]=0&iPathId=84738&aGeoCode[lat]=10.850516&aGeoCode[lng]=76.27108&iGeoDistanceItem=0&aCategoryRange=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5&aOverallLiking=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5&sOrderBy=relevance%20desc&bTopDealsOnly=false&iRoomType=9&aRooms[0][adults]=2&aRooms[0][children][]=1&cpt=8473803&iIncludeAll=0&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&

```
  @Test
  public void familyRoomFeature() throws InterruptedException
  {
      //Selecting Family Room from the dropdown
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js-fullscreen-hero']/div/form/div[2]/div/div/ul/li               [3]/button")).click();
      Thread.sleep(7000);
      //Selecting Adult age & there is another dropdown where it asks how many kids a user would have
      Select adultSelect=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select-num-adults-1']")));
      Select childSelect=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select-num-children-1']")));     
      adultSelect.selectByIndex(2);
      childSelect.selectByIndex(1); 
          //So once you select Adult & child selection, another selection dropdown gets visible
      //I get an error here and it doesn't select the child's age inspite of explicit wait
      WebElement childAge =driver.findElement(By.id("select-ages-children-1-78"));
      WebElement childAgedrop = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(childAge));
      Select childAgeFromSelect = new Select(childAgedrop);
      childAgeFromSelect.selectByIndex(3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The explicit wait is after the fact that you have already tried to find the child age element. Remove that line and the next one, and use the [visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-) expected condition.

Also the id used in the locator is generated dynamically and will fail on next run. Use an xpath locator like this - `"//select[starts-with(@id,'select-ages-children')]"` which will return a list of child age webelements.

Answer (score 0):

when dropdowns are dependent on each other, i.e if options are populated in a dropdown only after a previous element is selected, following wait can be used.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.xpath("//select[@id='select-ages-children-1-78']/option"), number))
```

The 'number' in the above code is variable. Some dropdowns show no text. In that case you can set it to 0. Where as some have just a '--Select--' option. In this case you can set it to 1.